# Paging on SharePoint Business Data List (BDC) webpart

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to change display the Business Data List webpart, to have a page forward/back button, but without using the 'Display toolbar' toolbar ?

The reason I ask is that the toolbar displays an actions menu, and an edit view menu which will just confuse matters for the users.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, we decided to use the paging bar.

We'll look at some custom form of control at a later date.... :-)

Comment: SharePoint 2010 has much improved functionality in this regard. If you are upgrading soon, you might condsider delaying custom code even more strongly.